# Como imprimir dos matrices juntas?

Tags: c++, c

Como puedo hacer para imprimir dos matrices de 4x4 juntas? con juntas me refiero a poner una matriz en la izquierda y la otra matriz en la derecha, asi como comparandolas

Comment: Imprime una matriz, y la otra la lado.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Buenas!

Si las matrices son del mismo tamaño (de filas sobretodo) puedes hacer dentro del mismo bucle, otro que recorra las columnas de la segunda matriz, una vez has recorrido las columnas de la primera, sería algo así:

```
    int m1[5][2] = { {1,2},{3,4}, {5,6}, {7,2}, {8,2} };
    int m2[5][2] = { {1,2},{2,2}, {2,2}, {2,2}, {2,2} };

    int alto = 5;
    int ancho_m1 = 2;
    int ancho_m2 = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < alto; i++) { // recorre las filas

        for (int j = 0; j < ancho_m1; j++) { // columnas de la primera matriz
            cout << m1[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout << "\t\t"; // tabuladores
        for (int k = 0; k < ancho_m2; k++) { // columnas de la segunda matriz
            cout << m2[i][k] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n"; // salto de línea
    }
```